# what strategy is cleaner for splitting redux store into slices?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have seen different strategies for splitting redux store into slices (each slice having a state, reducers, actions and actionCreators) and I am wondering what the pros and cons of each strategy is.

## Split based on backend Resources

In the restful world, backend models are named resources. Since the front-end let the user interact with objects of these classes, therefore we may have redux slices specific to each resource.

Example:
A slice for resource `Post` with a state consisting of keys such as `posts`, `selectedPost`, etc.

## Split based on frontend sub-modules

If you think of sub-modules as independent partitions of your app, each needs its own namespace in the rootStore.

Example:
A slice for profile, settings, and dashboard sub-modules

## Split by application pages (or Routes)

Each page with route, has its own slice.

Example:
User-Settings page, Organization-Settings page, Notifications-Settings page, Main-Settings page

Also I was wondering if there was other strategies I do not know about.

Answer (score 1):

I split my data by resource, after all we are talking about data here, what we only need to know is data scoping. It doesn't need to know which page is using it since these data could be used in a relationship of one is to many.

That way, when you need the data, you only need to think about the **data you need, nothing else** So the first option you gave is the best option, others are just pain in the ass. Redux gives you access to a global scoped state. If you manage it by routing or by module, then you would now need to memorise which route or module is using what data to retrieve it adding an additional complexity layer to your app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of other strategies than the ones you pointed here. However the strategy I follow is an hybrid of the first two you mention below. The reason for splitting reducers by BE resources and FE sub-modules is pretty straightforward as they both form the state of a feature.

If I understood your question correctly, then, you shouldn't rely entirely on BE resources to determine the strategy for managing your features state, since you'll need inner flexibility to control your components state (flags, counters, form values, etc.). Hence, Strategy 2 comes handy here. Alongside the fact that you definitely use BE info that is flowing to the same component.